# Dynamic instances of socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How can i split up my socket.io application to use it on multiple sites dynamically?

Ideally i´d like to have it based on the url so that localhost:3000/namespace1 dynamically creates namespace1.

I tried duplicating my socket.io code, but then i would need one port number per instance which is not ideal. And i would need to have a script duplicating the project which is not ideal.

I also have looked at https://github.com/PencilCode/dynamic.io but after hours of tries i cant get it to work.

Any tips would be hugely appreciated!

Here is my current server-side code:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var nsp = io.of('/namespace1');

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('connected');
  socket.on('create', function(room_name) {
    console.log('Someone is in the room: '+room_name);
    socket.join(room_name);
    socket.room = room_name;
  });
   socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      nsp.in(socket.room).emit('chat message', 'Message: '+msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: what is the problem? what error are you receiving?

Comment: The above code is working. I need help figuring out how to create namespace based on the url, or any other solution that could help me to dynamically create different instances of socket.io. 

There must be lots of people having done this but i can´t find any documented solutions.

Comment: socket.io has a built-in namespace feature that lets multiple namespaces share one actual connection.  Is there a reason that you aren't using that built-in feature?

Comment: Yes, because then i have to declare all namespaces in the server side code before starting the server. I need a dynamic way to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not against patching directly in libraries, you just have to delete three lines in [node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/b3fc530abefd384b3a89ff5493e97f3ef85098d4/lib/client.js#L64) (now line 64-67):

```
if (!nsp) {
  this.packet({ type: parser.ERROR, nsp: name, data : 'Invalid namespace'});
  return;
}
```

If you delete this three lines namespaces will be dynamically created in the socket.io server when they are used by clients.

```
var nsp = this.server.of(name);
```